# Cannot boot after upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: boot, upgrade

Ok, I got this problem which always happen when upgrading Ubuntu, never works on the go.

My problem now is my computer doesn't want to boot at all. Even when I switch to TTY terminal, I can not type anything. It displays AAC:host adapter dead -1. Non stop. What should I do? Please help me. All of my work is in my computer.

Comment: Can you list the details of your computer?

Comment: My computer is i7, 24GB ram, it has Nvidia Geforce (forgot the series) as graphic card. Maybe that's all.

Comment: Does your computer have a make, like `Dell` or `Acer` or `HP`? If your computer has a make, does it also have a model number?

Comment: The motherboard is ASUS but I don't know the series. This is my campus desktop PC so I've never check the model.

Comment: Do you have a backup before the upgrade?

Comment: No, but currently I use liveCD to back up the data that is in the KUbuntu installation drive. I think I will just reinstall everything. Most of my data is in seperate hard disk though.

Comment: Sounds good. Just to clarify, were you upgrading Ubuntu or upgrading KUbuntu?

Comment: I upgraded Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would strongly suggest booting from a usb key and copying over your existing data (I assume that you didn't encrypt your original partition). This can be done by simply booting from a Ubuntu 16.04 live usb. Data recovery is paramount here. As for the adapter message that appears, that sounds like a graphics card or display problem. The custom 4.8 kernel used in 16.10 could also be the culprit here, but that entirely depends on the hardware that you are using.